# C# Cannot read from App.config file in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, git, model-view-controller

I have an MVC project and am trying to store my API keys in a separate config file which I will ignore when pushing the code to Git. According to MSDN I should be able to store them in an App.config like like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="APIKey" value="APIKeyValue" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I should then be able to read from the file by creating a method in a model

```
  public class KeyTest 
  {
    public string KeyTestCall()
    {
      string testkey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("APIKey");
      return testkey;
    }
  }
```

and then invoke the method in my controller to assign the value from my App.config file (just so I know I'm getting the value).

```
public void Testing()
    {
        KeyTest k = new KeyTest();
        ViewBag.x = k;      
    }
```

At no point will the code break for a breakpoint, the build will succeed and I can't tell if I'm getting the value or not. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to above (re: `web.config` vs `app.config`) if you want to remove "secrets" from source control, [this is one way to do it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154(v=vs.100).aspx):

In `web.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <cofiguration>
      ....
         <appSettings file="AppKeys.config">
             <add key="SomeOtherSettingThatHasNoSecrets" value="foo" />
             ...
```

Then in a separte `AppKeys.config` file (you can name this whatever.config, sample as named in the above), that you don't add to `Git`/source control:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="SomeSecretKey" value="the secret" />
    ...
```

Note that `AppKeys.config` *doesn't* have an XML declaration.

Hth.

Answer (score 2):

For a web application such as an MVC app, it's a `Web.config` file, not an `App.config`

Comment: I have the same issue even after moving the appSettings into the Web.config

Comment: Use the accessor. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"]`